# Is there a way to set the deafault value of a bootstrap checkbox group to true?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-vue

I have a checkbox group that contains 21 checkboxes that are bound to an array.
Currently they are all unchecked by default, but I would like them all to be checked.
Looking at the documentation, it seems like the **checked="true"** method only works when you use individual checkboxes.
How can I accomplish this when it's a checkbox group?

```
<b-row>
  <b-col lg="2" class="mb-3">
    <b-form-checkbox-group stacked v-if="selectedPropertyId && tableLayout" v-model="visibleFieldKeys" :options="fields.slice(0,7)" text-field="label" value-field="key" inline/>
  </b-col>
  <b-col lg="2" class="mb-3">
    <b-form-checkbox-group stacked v-if="selectedPropertyId && tableLayout" v-model="visibleFieldKeys" :options="fields.slice(7,14)" text-field="label" value-field="key" inline/>
  </b-col>
  <b-col lg="2" class="mb-3">
    <b-form-checkbox-group stacked v-if="selectedPropertyId && tableLayout" v-model="visibleFieldKeys" :options="fields.slice(14,21)" text-field="label" value-field="key" inline/>
  </b-col>
</b-row>
```

I tried inserting the values manually to the array, which didn't do anything, and it's not exactly pretty code.

```
visibleFieldKeys: [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true,]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `visibleFieldKeys` shouldn't contain boolean.
But the *values* of your checkboxes.
In this case, that would be the `key` property from the objects in your `fields` array.

So you could map your fields and create a new array with all the keys and assign that to `visibleFieldKeys`

`visibleFieldKeys: fields.map(f => f.key]`